# Every $T_3$ space with a countable basis is $T_4$.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, second-countable

**Theorem.** *Every regular space with a countable basis is normal.*

*Proof.* Let X be a regular space with a countable basis $\mathcal{B}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X$. Each point $x$ of $A$ has a neighborhood $U$ disjoint from $B$. Using regularity, choose a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ whose closure lies in $U \dots$

I can't follow the last step made until this point; *Using regularity, choose a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ whose closure lies in $U$*.

I do know that *$X$ is a regular space if, given any nonempty closed set $F$ and any point $x$ that does not belong to $F$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $F$ that are disjoint.*

Could anyone help me with some insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define regular? In some places the definition of regular is "separate a point and a disjoint closed set by disjoint open sets" (I may be forgetting something like an additional $T_1$ assumption, but the point is the same).

Comment: Apply the regularity property to the point $x$ and the closed set $X\setminus U$ will give you that last step.

Comment: @WillieWong. So that would mean that $\overline{X\setminus{U}} \subset U$.   But how do I justify that the closure lies in $U$? Is this always true for any  space and any two closed subsets? Or does  the closure operation act proper to the regularity of the space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$ is a point. $U\ni x$ is open. $X\setminus U$ is closed. Regularity implies that there are disjoint neighborhoods $V \ni x$ and $V' \supset X\setminus U$.

We have
$$ V\cap V' = \emptyset \implies V \subseteq X \setminus V' $$
Note that the right hand side is the complement of an open set and so is closed. Take the closure on both sides we have
$$ \bar{V} \subseteq \overline{X\setminus V'} = X\setminus V'$$

Now since
$$ X\setminus U \subseteq V'$$
from de Morgan's laws we have
$$ X\setminus V' \subseteq U $$
and so 
$$ \bar{V} \subseteq U $$ 
as desired.

Comment: The proof works for a starting point $x$, but can we extend this proof further to show that normality holds for any arbitrary closed set given regularity and countable basis? I think the countability of the basis is crucial to prove normality, i.e. since the countablility of the basis was not used here...

Comment: @LinkL: my answer says **nothing** about normality. This answer **only** answer the question asked above, which is how regularity implies there exists a nbhd of $x$ whose closure sit in the set $U$. The proof of normality have more steps hidden by the ellipsis in the "proof" given in the original question above.