# Question about the proof of $T_3+$ countable basis $= T_4$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, separation-axioms

I have some doubts about the following proof,

**1.** Where was used the hypothesis of *countable basis*?

**2.** To prove that $X$ is $T_4$, for all  closed sets $F,G\subset $  X , there must be 2 open sets $V,V'$ such that $F\subset V,G\subset V'$ and $V\cap V'.$ In the proof given, $$V' \supset X\setminus U=F \ ?$$ and $$G=\overline V\subset U\ ?$$

---

Proof (made by Willie Wong MSE user at [Every $T_3$ space with a countable basis is $T_4$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291314/every-t-3-space-with-a-countable-basis-is-t-4))

$x$ is a point. $U\ni x$ is open. $X\setminus U$ is closed. Regularity implies that there are disjoint neighborhoods $V \ni x$ and $V' \supset X\setminus U$.

We have
$$ V\cap V' = \emptyset \implies V \subseteq X \setminus V' $$
Note that the right hand side is the complement of an open set and so is closed. Take the closure on both sides we have
$$ \bar{V} \subseteq \overline{X\setminus V'} = X\setminus V'$$

Now since
$$ X\setminus U \subseteq V'$$
from de Morgan's laws we have
$$ X\setminus V' \subseteq U $$
and so 
$$ \bar{V} \subseteq U $$ 
as desired.

Comment: The countable base part is used elsewhere. This is a lemma in the proof of the normality, just as I used in [my writeup](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/07.pdf). It's a standard fact that many text books routinely prove.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you have copied is not a proof of the statement you refer to at all.  Instead, it is a proof that if $X$ is regular and $U$ is a neighborhood of a point $x$ in $X$, then there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ whose closure is contained in $U$.

Comment: :( but the title of the question said: 'Every $T_3$ space with a countable basis is $T_4$'

Comment: I would suggest you try reading the entire question rather than just the title.

Comment: @bella The title is misleading. The result Eric quoted is a "lemma" in the proof of the title's result.